# Django ORM - How to concatenate or Group ManyToMany field values in queryset

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm

I am building my first Django App, am very new to it and have come undone trying to handle instances where a field has multiple values in a queryset.

My specific example is that I am trying to fetch all unique machine_name's with their most recent handover_id and the handover model's associated fields. ct_limitations is a ManyToManyField in the handover model and contains multiple values - Whilst I am expecting only 5 unique machines, one of which has two ct_limitations, I get a new row for each ct_limitaion value as below:

[MySQL Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF9Ga.png)

Any assistance or pointers would be greatly appreciated

**My code as follows:**

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Machine Type
class MachineType(models.Model):
    machine_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.machine_type)

# Purpose
class Purpose(models.Model):
    purpose = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.purpose

    class Meta:
        # Add verbose name
        verbose_name_plural = 'Purposes'

# Status
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.status

    class Meta:
        # Add verbose name
        verbose_name_plural = 'Statuses'


# CT Limitations
class CTLimitations(models.Model):
    ct_limitations = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name='CT limitations')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ct_limitations

    class Meta:
        # Add verbose name
        verbose_name_plural = 'CT limitations'

# Machine
class Machine(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    machine_type = models.ForeignKey(MachineType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    software_version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, verbose_name='Active?')
    setup_date = models.DateTimeField()
    retired_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.machine_name

class Roles(models.Model):
    roles = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.roles

    class Meta:
        # Add verbose name
        verbose_name_plural = 'User Roles'

# Handover
class Handover(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purpose = models.ForeignKey(Purpose, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    handover_start = models.DateTimeField()
    started_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='started_handover_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    staff_group = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    handover_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ended_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='ended_handover_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ct_limitations = models.ManyToManyField(CTLimitations, blank=True)
    error_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    intervention = models.BooleanField()
    locked = models.BooleanField()
    notes = models.TextField('Notes', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.machine_name} {self.handover_start}'

# Extend User model
class UserRoles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roles = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mpe = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='MPE?')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Handover, Machine
from django.db.models import Max, F


def index(request):
     qs_machine_handover = Machine.objects.filter(
        active=True,
        handover__handover_start__in=Machine.objects.values('id').annotate(
        max_handover=Max('handover__handover_start')).values('max_handover')
    ).annotate(
        most_recent_handover=Max('handover__handover_start'),
        handover_end=F('handover__handover_end'),
        purpose=F('handover__purpose__purpose'),
        machin_name=F('handover__machine_name__machine_name'),
        purpose_id=F('handover__purpose__id'),
        staff_group=F('handover__staff_group__roles'),
        status=F('handover__status__status'),
        status_id=F('handover__status_id'),
        ct_limitations=F('handover__ct_limitations__ct_limitations'),
        error_code=F('handover__error_code'),
        locked=F('handover__locked'),
        notes=F('handover__notes'),
        handover_id=F('handover__id')
    ).order_by('-machine_name')

    # Create Queryset based on most recent handover for each machine
    print(qs_machine_handover.query)
    data = {'m': qs_machine_handover}
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', data)

def add_user(request):
    return render(request, 'main/add_user.html')
```

I can get the desired result in MySQL via this query with Group By and concatenating but it looks like Django doesn't support this? Is my only option using raw sql or stored protocols?

```
SELECT 
    `main_machine`.`id`,
    `main_machine`.`machine_name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `main_ctlimitations`.`ct_limitations` ORDER BY `main_ctlimitations`.`ct_limitations` ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS `ct_limitations`,
    `main_machine`.`machine_type_id`,
    `main_machine`.`active`,
    MAX(`main_handover`.`handover_start`) AS `most_recent_handover`,
    `main_handover`.`handover_end` AS `handover_end`,
    `main_purpose`.`purpose` AS `purpose`,
    T4.`machine_name` AS `machin_name`,
    `main_handover`.`purpose_id` AS `purpose_id`,
    `main_roles`.`roles` AS `staff_group`,
    `main_status`.`status` AS `status`,
    `main_handover`.`status_id` AS `status_id`,
    `main_handover`.`error_code` AS `error_code`,
    `main_handover`.`locked` AS `locked`,
    `main_handover`.`notes` AS `notes`,
    `main_handover`.`id` AS `handover_id`
FROM
    `main_machine`
        INNER JOIN
    `main_handover` ON (`main_machine`.`id` = `main_handover`.`machine_name_id`)
        INNER JOIN
    `main_purpose` ON (`main_handover`.`purpose_id` = `main_purpose`.`id`)
        INNER JOIN
    `main_machine` T4 ON (`main_handover`.`machine_name_id` = T4.`id`)
        INNER JOIN
    `main_roles` ON (`main_handover`.`staff_group_id` = `main_roles`.`id`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `main_status` ON (`main_handover`.`status_id` = `main_status`.`id`)
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `main_handover_ct_limitations` ON (`main_handover`.`id` = `main_handover_ct_limitations`.`handover_id`)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    `main_ctlimitations` ON (`main_handover_ct_limitations`.`ctlimitations_id` = `main_ctlimitations`.`id`)
WHERE
     (`main_machine`.`active` = TRUE
        AND `main_handover`.`handover_start` IN (SELECT 
            MAX(U1.`handover_start`) AS `max_handover`
        FROM
            `main_machine` U0
                LEFT OUTER JOIN
            `main_handover` U1 ON (U0.`id` = U1.`machine_name_id`)
        GROUP BY U0.`id`
        ORDER BY NULL))
GROUP BY `main_machine`.`machine_name`
ORDER BY `main_machine`.`machine_name` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your logic into simpler steps. And, instead of using a base model such as `Machine` to query and annotate data you can query `Handover` directly.

For instance we can combine [`.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) and [`.distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to fetch unique machine names. Then, loop through and use these values to filter `Handover` QuerySet for its [`.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#last) record and append it to a list. Here is an example:

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    """
    List last handover per distinct machine name
    """
    machines = (
        Machine.objects.values_list("machine_name", flat=True)
        .distinct()
    )

    handovers = []
    for machine in machines:
        # Note that this query is odd because how you named your fields.
        # Instead should be something like ".filter(machine__name=machine)"
        handover = (
            Handover.objects.filter(machine_name__machine_name=machine)
            .last()
        )
        handovers.append(handover)
    return render(request, "main/home.html", {"handovers": handovers})
```

main/home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #001C30;">
    {% for handover in handovers %}
    <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #2D4356; color: white; border: 1px solid #001C30;">
        <h3>{{handover.machine_name.machine_name}}</h3>
        <p>Purpose: {{handover.purpose.purpose}}</p>
        <p>Started at: {{handover.handover_start}}</p>
        <p>Staff: {{handover.staff_group.roles}}</p>
        <p>Status: {{handover.status.status}}</p>
        <p>{{handover.error_code}}</p>
        <p>{{handover.notes}}</p>
        
        {% if handover.ct_limitations.all %}
            <p>Limitations:</p>
            <ul>
            {% for limitation in handover.ct_limitations.all %}
                <li>{{limitation.ct_limitations}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>Limitations: None</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest that you change your `Models` fields names to improve code readability. As you can see it's very confusing to access data.

Comment: Thank you, this looks a much simpler and more effective way of doing it.